# Probability of $\limsup X_n/n$ being zero or infinite

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

This is Exercise 5.1.3 from *Achim Klenke: »Probability Theory — A Comprehensive Course«.*

> *Exercise:* Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. nonnegative random variables. By virtue of the Borel–Cantelli lemma, show that
>   \begin{equation*}
>   \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} X_n =
>   \begin{cases}
>     0 \text{ a.s.}, & \text{ if } \mathbf{E}[X_1] < \infty,\\
>     \infty \text{ a.s.}, & \text{ if } \mathbf{E}[X_1] = \infty.
>   \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}

*Solution:* We show the first row. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Using that the $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are nonnegative, we get
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{P}\bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n/n < \varepsilon\bigr] = 1 - \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_n/n \geq \varepsilon \; \text{ i.o.}\}\bigr] = 1 - \mathbf{P}\Bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \, \{X_n/n \geq \varepsilon\}\Bigr] \, .
\end{equation*}
Using that $\mathbf{E}[X_1] <\infty$ and $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are identically distributed, we see that:
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_n/n \geq \varepsilon\} \bigr] = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_1 \geq n  \varepsilon\}\bigr] \cdot \varepsilon \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\cdot \underbrace{\mathbf{E}[X_1]}_{<\infty} < \infty\, .
\end{equation*}

The Borel-Cantelli lemma now gives us
$\mathbf{P}\Bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \, \{X_n/n \geq \varepsilon\}\Bigr] = 0$.

So for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $\mathbf{P}\bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n/n < \varepsilon\bigr] = 1$ and since $\mathbf{P}$ is upper semicontinuous $\mathbf{P}\bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n/n = 0 \bigr] = 1$

Now we show the second row. Let $M \geq 1$, then
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{P}\bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n/n \geq M \}\bigr] = \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_n/n \geq M \; \text{ i.o.}\}\bigr] = \mathbf{P}\Bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \, \{X_n/n \geq M \}\Bigr] \, .
\end{equation*}
Using that $\mathbf{E}[X_1] = \infty$ and $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are identically distributed and $\mathbf{P}[X_n/n \geq 0] = 1$ we see that:
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_n/n \geq M\} \bigr] = -1 + \frac{1}{M} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_1 \geq n  M\}\bigr] \cdot M \geq -1 + \frac{1}{M}\cdot \underbrace{\mathbf{E}[X_1]}_{=\infty} = \infty\, .
\end{equation*}

$X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent, so we can use the Borel-Cantelli lemma and we obtain that 
$\mathbf{P}\Bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \, \{X_n/n \geq M\}\Bigr] = 1$.

So for all $M \geq 1$ we have $\mathbf{P}\bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n/n \geq M \bigr] = 1$ and since $\mathbf{P}$ is upper semicontinuous $\mathbf{P}\bigl[\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n/n = \infty \bigr] = 1$. $\square$

---

Could you please check my proof?

Thank you!

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: can you please explain why \begin{equation*}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbf{P}\bigl[\{X_1 \geq n  M\}\bigr] \cdot M \geq   \cdot \underbrace{\mathbf{E}[X_1]}_{=\infty} = \end{equation*}

Comment: @Lambda87 $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbf P\left[X_1 \geq nM\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mathbf P \left[kM \geq X_1 < (k+1)M\right] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^k \mathbf P\left[k \geq \frac 1 M X_1 < k+1\right] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbf P\left[k \geq \frac 1 M X_1 < k+1\right] \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int \frac 1 M X_1 \mathbb 1_{\left\{k \leq \frac 1 M X_1 < k+1\right\}} \, d\mathbf P = \frac 1 M \mathbf E[X_1]$$